# Python/Flask web site for the www

Tags: python, flask, web, cloud, hosting

How to deploy a **python/flask** site on my host (OVH or IONOS or other)?
My site works in *localhost*.

## But I would like to share it on the web.

Thanks for your help.

I have no idea how to put a python/flask site on a shared host. I'm not knowledgeable enough in this area.

Comment: [Deploying Flask apps to production](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/deploying/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're serious about deploying your webapp to the vast realm of the internet, you will need to use a viable framework to do so.
Something like apache should do the job.
I won't go into detail as to how to deploy a webapp as there are many tutorials out there, but I'll provide some resources below:

- https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/mod_wsgi/
- https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-securely-deploy-flask-with-apache-in-a-linux-server-environment
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFBRVJPhDGY
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w0QDAg85Oow

Also remember to activate your SSL/TLS certificate (easy way to do that would be for example certbot) and enable HSTS.